# How to JQuery sum input values and then multiply with price

Tags: jquery

Currently working on shopify and this is the link that i am working on.

[Link](https://www.imabelleshop.com/collections/fashion-top/products/basic-long-sleeved-raglan-camo-sleeve)

I am trying to have the total amount shown in the table when some quantity is typed in to the input boxes but cannot figure it out.

Please help.

Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead style="background:#ccc;" >
        <tr>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th>Item #</th>
            <th>Pack</th>
            <th>Pack Price</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
{% for variant in product.variants %}
    {% if variant.available %}
        <tr class="{% cycle 'pure-table-odd', '' %}">
            <td>
                <a href="{{ variant.url | collection }}" >
                <center><img src="{{ variant.image | default: product.featured_image | img_url: 'small' }}" alt="{{ variant.title | escape }}" style="width:50px;" /></center>
                </a>
                <center><div>{{ variant.title }}</div></center>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ variant.url | collection }}">
                <center>{{ variant.sku }}</center>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <center><div>
        {% if settings.show-quantity %}
                <input min="0" {% unless variant.inventory_management == blank or variant.inventory_policy == 'continue' %} max="{{ variant.inventory_quantity }}" {% endunless %} type="text" id="quantity" class="quantity addnumber" name="updates[{{ variant.id }}]" value="0" tabindex="1" />
        {% endif %}
                </div></center>  
            </td>
            <td>
                <center>{{ variant.price | money }}</center>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    <tfoot style="background:#ccc;">
        <tr>
            <td><center>&nbsp;</center></td>
            <td><center>Total</center></td>
            <td><center><input type='text' id='totaladdnumber' class="quantity" disabled /></center></td>
            <td><center><input type='text' id='totaladdprice' class="quantity" disabled /></center></td>
            <td><center>&nbsp;</center></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.addnumber').keyup(function () {

    // initialize the sum (total price) to zero
    var sum = 0;

    // we use jQuery each() to loop through all the textbox with 'price' class
    // and compute the sum for each loop
    $('.addnumber').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });

    // set the computed value to 'totalPrice' textbox
    $('#totaladdnumber').val(sum);
});
```

Comment: `price` class, or `addnumber`?

Comment: #totaladdprice. which is in tfoot

Comment: You misunderstand. Comment says "we use jQuery each() to loop through all the textbox with 'price' class" but the code immediately after that reads `$('.addnumber').each(...)`!

Comment: I am sorry.. not really good at jquery and not understanding your comment.

Comment: @JonKim he means where in your HTML did you place these elements: `<input class='price'>` and `<input class="addnumber">`?

Comment: Oh ok! <input class="addnumber">